# How can I solve the error: 'int' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist

```py
def foo(x, a, b, i, j):
    k = j
    ct = 0
    while k > i-1:
        if x[k] <= b and not (x[k] <= a):
            ct = ct + 1
        k = k - 1
    return ct

    x = (11,10,10,5,10,15,20,10,7,11)
    y = [10000000000000000000]
    m = 0 

    while m < 10000000000000000000:  
      y[m] = m   
      m = m +1

    print(foo(x,8,18,3,6)) 
    print(foo(x,10,20,0,9))
    print(foo(x,8,18,6,3))
    print(foo(x,20,10,0,9)) 
    print(foo(x,6,7,8,8))
    # Please be careful with typos for the output of the following lines!
    print(foo(y,
         111112222233333, # five 1's, then five 2's, then five 3's
         999998888877777, # five 9's, then five 8's, then five 7's
         222223333344444, # five 2's, then five 3's, then five 4's
         905003340009900023))
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
last) <ipython-input-17-d3d2cd54b367> in <module>()
     14 
     15 while m <  10000000000000000000:
---> 16   y[m] = m
     17   m = m +1
     18

TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Your title and the provided content doesn't match

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain what this code is supposed to do - this will make it much easier to understand where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In python, when you write `y = [10000000000000000000]`, you are creating an array with a single item in index `0`, which has `10000000000000000000` as value. And, maybe, your idea was to define an array with `10000000000000000000` items in it?

If that is the case, what you want to do is: `y = []` to initialize an array/list. In python, you don't specify the size of arrays, they are dynamic. But you need to use methods to remove or to add new items. You can change an existing item by using index, though.

If you fix that, you will still get an Exception where the arrow is pointing at, in the Traceback, because you are trying to modify the value of an index that does not exist. Since you instantiated the array as `y = [10000000000000000000]`, you only have a value in index `0`. It works the first time, because the loop starts at index `0`, when it sets `y[0] = 0`. But when `m` get incremented and it tries `y[1] = 1`, the array does not have that index, which will raise `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`.

If you want to initialize an array with `10000000000000000000` items in it, you could do:

```
y = []
for i in range(10000000000000000000):
    y.append(i)
```

or

```
y = [i for i in range(10000000000000000000)]
```

More about `range()` function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

More about array/list: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html